# Rotate Location Marker along Road Curves and store Rotated Angle Value in Firebase Realtime DB

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase-realtime-database, leaflet, maps

I have a web app to capture realtime moving location data of a car rider and updates it in Firebase Realtime Database. I am able to display a car icon marker displaying rider's realtime moving location and can store that location data (Rider Name, Latitude, Longitude, Accuracy) to Firebase RTDB. But One problem in it is, if the rider rides through a curvy road, then also the car icon marker seems to be in a fixed bearing position. I want to rotate the marker according to the road curve and store the rotation angle value also in firebase DB. Is there any way to achieve this requirement?

**My code is as given below:**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Rider Module</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A==" crossorigin=""/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA==" crossorigin=""></script>
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.9.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.9.1/firebase-database.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.9.1/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
<style>
    html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map" style="height:100%; width:100%; background-color:#eeeeee;"></div>
    <script>
    mbUrl1 = 'https://{s}.google.com/vt/lyrs=m&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}'; 
    mbUrl2 = 'https://{s}.google.com/vt/lyrs=s,h,p&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}';
    mbUrl3 = 'https://{s}.google.com/vt/lyrs=m@221097413,traffic&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}';
    const streets = L.tileLayer(mbUrl1, {maxZoom: 18, subdomains:['mt0','mt1','mt2','mt3']}),
    hybrid = L.tileLayer(mbUrl2, {maxZoom: 18, subdomains:['mt0','mt1','mt2','mt3']}),
    traffic = L.tileLayer(mbUrl3, {maxZoom: 18, subdomains:['mt0','mt1','mt2','mt3']});
    const map = L.map("map", {
        center: [8.4819, 77.0361],
        zoom: 18,
        maxZoom: 18,
        minZoom: 18,
        layers: [streets]
    });
    var baseLayers = {
        "Streets": streets,
        "Hybrid": hybrid,
        "Traffic": traffic
    };
    L.control.layers(baseLayers).addTo(map);
    var firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        databaseURL: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        projectId: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        appId: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    firebase.analytics();
    this.database = firebase.database();

    var marker;
    var ridername="Rider 1";    
    var username="rider1@abcde.com";
    var i=0;
    var pointA=[];
    function onLocationFound(e) 
        {
            var lat= e.latlng.lat;
            var lng= e.latlng.lng;
            var accuracy= e.accuracy/2;  
            if (marker) { map.removeLayer(marker); }    
            var markerIcon = new L.Icon({
                iconUrl: 'markericon.png',
                iconSize:     [30, 45],
                iconAnchor:   [15, 47],
                popupAnchor:  [0, -50]
            });
            marker= L.marker(e.latlng,{icon: markerIcon}).addTo(map);
            marker.bindPopup("<b>Rider Name:</b> " + ridername + "<br><b>Latitude:</b> " + lat + "<br><b>Longitude:</b> " + lng + "<br><b>Accuracy:</b> " + accuracy.toFixed(2) + "M Radius").addTo(map).openPopup();   
            firebase.database().ref('locations/users/'+username).set(
                {
                    ridername: ridername,
                    lat: lat,
                    lng : lng,
                    accuracy : accuracy
                });
            if (i==0)
                {   
                    pointA[i] = new L.LatLng(lat, lng);
                }
            ++i;
            pointA[i]= new L.LatLng(lat, lng);
            var pointList = [pointA[i-1], pointA[i]];
            new L.Polyline(pointList, {color: 'red'}).addTo(map);           
        }
    function onLocationError(e) {
            alert(e.message);
            var user = firebase.database().ref('locations/users/');
            user.child(username).remove();      
        }
    map.on('locationfound', onLocationFound);
    map.on('locationerror', onLocationError);
    map.locate({setView: true, watch: true, enableHighAccuracy: true, maxZoom: 18});
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#markers--renderers and in particular https://github.com/bbecquet/Leaflet.RotatedMarker

Comment: This plugin can be used to rotate marker to a particular angle only which is the second part of my requirement. But how to get bearing angle value of the road curves?

Comment: One question at a time; break up your problem into smaller problems. Do read https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions